# Can I use Python Numba on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, numba

Is it possible to use the Python package Numba in web-apps that are running on Google App Engine?

Is it possible to use the caching feature of Numba, so the functions don't have to be JIT-compiled every time they are run on Google App Engine? Or is there another way of achieving the same effect, e.g. by somehow building the Numba cache on my own computer and including it when deploying the app to Google's servers?

Are there any other limitations or requirements to be aware of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Upon looking around. I found this similar [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/112765995)

Wherein it is already submitted to Google Cloud Engineers. You can also hit the "+1" to be alert when an update comes

Please be advised that this doesn't have a specific ETA but you can reply to the thread and keep track of its progress.

For other feature request or bugs that you may encounter for similar or other Google Cloud products and services, you may check out this link on [Google Cloud issue tracking system and product feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I have upvoted your answer, but I will leave my question open in case it becomes possible in the future, or if someone knows a workaround. One possibility seems to be Numba's AOT (Ahead-of-Time) compilation https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/pycc.html although it is apparently more limited than JIT, and it will be deprecated in the future when they have a replacement for it. Another option would be to use Cython but that is much more complicated than Numba.